# Parse JSON with facebook sdk

Tags: android, json, facebook

I was wondering how to get the value of "name" for the following json text with facebook sdk. Assuming I have already got the access token. Any thoughts? Many thanks!

```
enter code here

  {
    "id": "100005065353669", 
    "music": {
      "data": [
        {
          "category": "Musician/band", 
          "name": "Eason Chan", 
          "id": "105468519487919", 
          "created_time": "2013-06-05T20:33:26+0000"
        }
      ], 
      "paging": {
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/100005065353669/musiclimit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=105468519487919"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a dynamic JSON key in a Nested JSON result](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7304002/how-to-parse-a-dynamic-json-key-in-a-nested-json-result)

Comment: you can use JSON.parse in JS.  see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4935684/788154